# List Azure Security Center Policies status using Azure AZ Powershell Cmdlets

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-security, azure-policy

Please let me know the command available to list Security Policies associated with particular subscription.

What I am trying to list is below:

In the navigation panel, choose Security policy to access Policy Management portal.

1. On the Policy Management page, click on the name of the subscription that you want to examine to access the selected subscription configuration settings.
2. On the Security Policy page, in the Compute and Apps category, check the Vulnerabilities in security configuration on your machines should be remediated setting status. If the configuration setting is set to Disabled, the OS vulnerability monitoring is not enabled for the Microsoft Azure virtual machines (VMs) available in the current subscription.

[image: Expected]

Want to list above policy status using powershell command.

Using Get-AzPolicyAssignment[image]

Not retrieving the same policies as compared to whatever listed on portal.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I don't misunderstand, you want to check the status of the `Vulnerabilities in security configuration on your machines should be remediated` parameter in the policy `[Preview]: Enable Monitoring in Azure Security Center`.

[image]

Currently, we can get it with

```
$policy = Get-AzPolicyAssignment | Where-Object {$_.Properties.displayName -eq '[Preview]: Enable Monitoring in Azure Security Center'}
```

[image]

but seems we could not get the parameter' status in this command by default

[image]

---

If your ultimate goal is to check the status, if it is `Disabled`, then you will set it with `AuditIfNotExists`.

If so, you could use the commands below to set it directly, no matter if it is `Disabled` or `AuditIfNotExists`, it will both be set to `AuditIfNotExists`(If you want to set it to `Disabled`, just change the command with `systemConfigurationsMonitoringEffect = "Disabled"`).

```
$policy = Get-AzPolicyAssignment | Where-Object {$_.Properties.displayName -eq '[Preview]: Enable Monitoring in Azure Security Center'}
Set-AzPolicyAssignment -Id $policy.ResourceId -PolicyParameterObject @{systemConfigurationsMonitoringEffect = "AuditIfNotExists"}
```

Then we check the `$policy.Properties.parameters`, it appears. Check in the portal, you will find it also works.

[image]

**Update**:

If you just use `Get-AzPolicyAssignment` without any parameter, the `Initiative` policy will not return.

Navigate to the `Policy` -> `Assignments` in the portal, find the `Initiative` type policy you want, click it, copy the `Assignment ID`.

[image]

Then use the command below.

```
Get-AzPolicyAssignment -Id <Assignment ID>
```

If you want to get all the policies under the `Initiative` policy, try the command below, the  `$policies` is that you want.

```
$initiative = Get-AzPolicyAssignment -Id <Assignment ID>
$policies = (Get-AzPolicySetDefinition -Id $initiative.Properties.policyDefinitionId).Properties.policyDefinitions
```

[image]

Check them in the portal:

[image]

Comment: Tried with  Get-AzPolicyAssignment command but its not showing all the policies which are listed in the azure portal under security policy. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @PrashantShete What do you want to list? Could you provide a screenshot in your question?

Comment: updated the question with screenshots, please check.

Comment: @PrashantShete Navigate to the `Policy` -> `Assignments` in the portal, follow this screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZJgD.png, check your policy if exist or not, if it exists, use `Get-AzPolicyAssignment | Where-Object {$_.Properties.displayName -eq '<Policy name>'}` to have try.

Comment: @ Joy wang - yeah I could see the same policies listed in portal as of https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPvMe.jpg. Two of them are initiative, is there any way we can describe the initiative using AZ power-shell command to list all the policies under it?